# python 3.8 - How to check if a folder contains file/s only - NOT sub-folder

Tags: python

I have folder 201 and subfolder 202 then some files in the 202 folder. Now i want to check in folder 201 if files exist but it always shows yes as there's sub-folder (202).

201 folder has no files and 202 have 3 files.

There is not a single file folder 201 but below code prints " files found in the directory."

```
import os

p = r"C:\sample_test\201"

for files in os.walk(p):
    if files:
        print(p, " files found in the directory.")
    if not files:
        print(p, " files NOT found in the directory.")
```

Comment: Did you read the docs for `os.walk`? Did you attempt to print `files`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `os.listdir` and `os.path.isfile`:

```py
import os

p = r"C:\sample_test\201"
has_files = any(fse for fse in os.listdir(p) if os.path.isfile(fse))
```

Comment: for p = r"C:\sample_test\201" got result "False" and for p = r"C:\sample_test\201\202" also got same result "False". I was expecting "True" for p = r"C:\sample_test\201\202".

Comment: I have parquet files in 202 folder, Is it why Isfile function not recognising as it is flat file?

Comment: test using the whole path it is working (got TRUE value) for individual file with Isfile(). but in above code if i use as only file name with extension it gives me "False".

Comment: Got it finally. below code worked.  a = str(p+"\\")
has_files = any(fse for fse in os.listdir(p) if os.path.isfile(a+fse))